# Using LessCSS with the Blueprint framework?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to use LessCSS with Blueprint?

What do I need to get started?

Comment: what your base language.  php/ruby/java ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Link for a starting point: [Using .less To Simplify BluePrintCSS](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/using-less-to-simplify-blueprintcss/)

Comment: I followed the link, and faced a problem where I couldn't get blue print to work. Turns out, blueprint css file could not get imported. So, I changed its name to screen.less - the file was getting read then. + it did not seem to like the fact that my base div had .container class -- so I put that into the html. otherwise it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://pageblox.com/) rapid layout/prototyping tool uses LESS.js/Blueprint for the interface and Blueprint for the generated code.